# Installed Ubuntu after using win10 for a while (now dualboot). Shouldn't physically having data on my hard drive be reflected in Ubuntu somehow?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hard-drive, files, filesystem

**PLEASE SKIP TO THE TLDR** I made this needlessly long because I'm extremely confused, no need to read all of it, just skip to the TLDR. I'll keep everything there just because why not, but please don't bother reading all of it lol, the TLDR sums up my question.

So I've been using my laptop with Win10 for around a year now, and obviously over that time I've installed various things and created files and etc. etc. so the physical space on my hard drive is taken up. Literally, **physically** there is now less space on my hard drive.

In Windows I can clearly see that reflected, just by using File Explorer and browsing all the files and folders I have. I can see exactly what is taking up space (ex. oh this file is 1GB large, so that's why I have 1GB less space on my hard drive).

How can I see that in Ubuntu? Like I said, there's already stuff on my hard drive (around 200GB worth of data). It's not like Linux will just completely ignore what's already there right? The data is still physically there.

How can I see all the various files, programs, folders, etc. that's taking up space on my hard drive in Ubuntu? The reason I'm so confused is because, when I use Ubuntu instead of Win10, it seems like a barren, store-bought device with nothing on it. Using the file explorer on Ubuntu, I've just randomly been searching through all the various folders, but I haven't found any of the files that are supposed to be on my hard drive (files that I can easily find when I use Win10).

Also some guides mention "sharing" files between Win10 and Ubuntu. But I don't see why I have to do that because they're both on the same device, both accessing the same hard drive. The files are right there on the hard drive, why do I need to "share" them to Ubuntu? Ubuntu is accessing the same hard drive as Win10 is accessing, so it should be able to see the files already on the hard drive shouldn't it?

Sorry for the long post, I'm just extremely confused and having trouble explaining myself.

**TLDR**: I've used my laptop with Win10 for around a year, I just recently set up a dual boot for and have lots of files on my computer, and lots of my hard drive space is taken up. In Windows 10, I can see all my files, and I can see what exactly is taking up space on my hard drive. In Ubuntu, I can't find any of those files. But that doesn't make any sense because the files are still there; they physically exist on my hard drive, so they have to still be there. Yet I can't find them when I use Ubuntu (or maybe I'm not looking in the right place). Win10 and Ubuntu are accessing the same hard drive, so even if I make a .txt file on Win10, since that .txt file now physically exists on the hard drive, I should be able to see it on Ubuntu right? What does this mean/where should I be looking?

I'm guessing a possibility is that there's a folder or something that has all the stuff that I see on Win10? And on Win10, there's a folder that would have all the stuff I normally see on Ubuntu? I'm just confused because I can't find data that is physically there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you turn Windows fast start up or always on hibernation? Linux NTFS driver will not mount NTFS that is hibernated nor if it needs chkdsk.  See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 0):

The two operating systems exist in separate partitions.  It sounds like you haven't mounted the Windows partition.  Unless MS are using a new file system i don't know about, try the following:

1. Open the Terminal
2. Type the following   `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`  and enter your password to proceed.  You'll see a list of your hard drives and partitions.  Here are mine:

> sda             894.3G
>
> ├─sda1 vfat       200M /boot/efi        EFI
>
> ├─sda2 hfsplus  791.6G                  Macintosh HD
>
> ├─sda3 hfsplus    620M                  Recovery HD
>
> ├─sda4 hfsplus    191M                  UbuntuBootLoader
>
> ├─sda5 swap       7.6G [SWAP]
>
> └─sda6 ext4        94G /
>
> sr0              1024M

3. Find the partition which corresponds to your windows partition (here sda2 is my OSX partition).
4. Mount that partition.  [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount) is the relevant guide.  `/mnt` is for temporary mounting
5. If you want to automate the mounting process, read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

**Edit** Proceed with caution.  If you do not need the ability to write the the Windows partition, mount it as read only.  It is possible to accidentally wipe out Windows.